# Como atualizar versão do SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, sql-server-localdb

Tenho um projeto de site em ASP.NET MVC compartilhado no team e no pc de casa. Consigo conectar no DB normalmente, porém, quando vou logar algum usuário cadastrado no site no pc do trampo ele acontece o seguinte erro:

> The database 'aspnet-NerdChest-20160621052548' cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 851 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>   Cannot open database "aspnet-NerdChest-20160621052548" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'FELIPE-PC\Felipe'.

Como resolver para poder trabalhar nos dois ambientes?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como atualizar sql no visual studio](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139182/como-atualizar-sql-no-visual-studio)