# Como atualizar sql no visual studio 2015

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

Estou em um projeto ASP MVC .Quando tento fazer um login ou usar o banco de dados acontece o seguinte erro:

> The database 'aspnet-NerdChest-20160621052548' cannot be opened
>   because it is version 852. This server supports version 851 and
>   earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Cannot open database
>   "aspnet-NerdChest-20160621052548" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'FELIPE-PC\Felipe'.

acabei de atualizar o sql no que ta de servidor e no pc que trabalho com ele ta mais antiga e mesmo assim nao deixa usar o sql...
meu db ja esta no padrao (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB. nao sei mais oque faço

Comment: Cara, não fique criando varias perguntas para o mesmo assunto, tenha paciência para que alguém responda a sua pergunta, caso seja preciso altere e esclareça melhor seu erro.

Comment: perdao... axei que tinha feito a pergunta no stack in inglish

Answer (score 1):

Felipe,
Tua pergunta ficou faltando alguns dados, tipo

- qual é a versão do VSStudio que tua usa
- o nome da instancia do banco
- Se o banco é localdb o SQLExpress como serviço

Se for localdb segue essa solução para VS 2013
Tente alterar  Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections > SQL Server Instance Name.
O padrão para VS2013 é (LocalDB)\v11.0 , isso sendo o localdb  SQL 2012

Mudar para (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: Na verdade não falta informação. Este erro só ocorre com o Microsoft SQL Server LocalDb.

Comment: perdao... uso o VSCommunity 2015... LocalDB... estou usando o identity do mvc que ja vem pronto... so fiz algumas alteraçoes na tabela adicionando os campos que eu precisava... a instancia ja esta com o nome padra (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB